# Removing Repository Pattern from infyom laravel generator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, repository-pattern, crud-admin-generator

I have used a laravel CRUD Generator [Infyom Laravel Generator](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.3/installation) to generate CRUD code. By default it uses Repository Pattern which is confusing for me. Is there any way to remove only Repository Pattern without affecting working app (I am developing it) ?

Comment: Laravel doesn't use repositories on its own, that's coming purely from Infyom. So you should probably ask them: https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/issues

Comment: As far as I know, the Infyom generator is pretty new so I doubt they have an option to change this.  You can always modify the controllers to use the Model directly as I'm assuming that's your issue.

Comment: Sorry I am new to developing and laravel. I edited question. I asked here because someone with similar experience on stackoverflow might be help

Comment: you can set repository pattern false in laravel_generator file. you can find repository_pattern in options https://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/6.0/configuration#options. once set false and generate repository not generate. please check docs